# Запятая после "давайте": "давай(те) я (что-то сделаю)"

Tags: пунктуация

В этом случае *давай(те)*, очевидно, частица. И после неё запятую не ставят. Однако же в Нацкорпусе есть множество примеров как и без запятой, так и с ней. ***Хочется понять почему.*** Неужели там столько ошибок?!

Есть ещё вариант, когда "давай(те)" глагол. Например, в ответ на вопрос: "Давайте (=хорошо), я сделаю так-то и так-то". В этом случае запятая нужна.

Но вот на [этой](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E4%E0%E2%E0%E9%F2%E5%20%FF&p=35) странице собрано много примеров с запятой, и во всех них *давайте*, скорее всего, частица. Только в примерах из Потапенко и Лескова оно ещё может быть глаголом, но вряд ли. В остальных примерах это точно частица.

Answer (score 1):

**Давайте** действительно частица.

> Давай(те), в зн. частицы. (с инф. нсв. или с 1 л. мн. ч. буд. вр.). Разг. 1. Выражает приглашение к совместному действию или побуждение к действию. Д. мириться! Давайте посидим, отдохнём, покурим. Спи д.! Давайте поторапливайтесь.

Однако надо учитывать и год издания. Все примеры не ранее 1800-х годов. Впрочем, в интернете некоторые из приведенных примеров встречаются без запятой.

*где тарелки и все, давайте я сама возьму и накрою стол, а вы несите кушанье.* **[Н. Г. Чернышевский. Что делать? (1863)]**

**― Так никто не хочет? ― Пожалуй, давайте я возьму… Так и быть уж… [А. П. 
Чехов. Елка (1884)]**

. **― «Чего же лучше? Давайте я, пожалуй, буду суфлировать вам». ― «Не нужно; я знаю прежнего Державина наизусть». [С. П. Жихарев. Записки современника (1806-1809**