# Ставится ли запятая после «давай»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частица, разговорная-речь

> Давай(,) двигай отседова!

Возможна ли постановка запятой в этом случае, если подразумевается «давай быстрее»?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435201/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8e?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C47.6139  Повтор вопроса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В таких коротких побудительных фразах пунктуация целиком зависит от интонации, отдельных ударений, пауз, экспрессии. Поэтому возможны оба варианта (вместо запятой можно увидеть и восклицательный знак).

***Давай двИгай отседова!*** ― ударение на одном слове.
***ДавАй, двИгай отседова!*** ― два ударения.

**[Примеры из Нацкорпуса](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9)**

**Без запятой**:

*Ликуська обернулась, но ничего не сказала, ее глаза начали медленно наполняться слезами. ― **Давай двигай,** ― велел парень в форме. Лика молча повиновалась.* [Дарья Донцова. Уха из золотой рыбки (2004)]

*― Эй, мыслитель! **Давай двигай** картошку лопать, ― позвала Мила. ― Остынет.* [Вадим Громов. Компромат для олигарха (2000)]

***Давай двигай** галопом, пять минут на переход, а то поджарка стынет…* [М. Л. Халфина. Внуки (1970-1980)]

**С запятой:**

― ***Давай, двигай** на телевидение, ― сказал Илюшин и дружески толкнул меня в спину.* [Вячеслав Костиков. Роман с президентом (1996)]

*Идет? – **Давай, двигай.** Если не вернешься, мы без тебя пойдем.* [Александра Маринина. Светлый лик смерти (1996)]

*Так что **давай, двигай.** Пуля ― дура, штык ― молодец!* [Ю. И. Визбор. Альтернатива вершины Ключ (1981)]

> [**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=290541)
>
> Возможны варианты: *Ну, давай переезжай! Ну давай, переезжай!* Пунктуация зависит от интонации.